# WordPress How to add rewrite url permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks, wordpress-rest-api

I need to understand how to integrate a rewrite url so that I can get the same wording on a wordpress site:

```
xxxx.com/{$author_username}/{$id_post}
```

The purpose is to have a shortlink of a wordpress post and easily readable.

Can you tell me how I can do this?

Unfortunately there are now conflicts..

Thank you!!

Comment: Can't you just set the permalink structure to `%author%/%post_id%` in settings?

Comment: @Stender I would like to insert another article display page in addition to the default one with rewrite url because now an article has a link like this hello-world-this-is-an-example and i would another page like this: /autorXXX/456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the structure of your slugs, you don't need to modify any core files in **WordPress** or add additional functions, you can simply modify the structure inside of **WP > Settings > Permalinks**.

Please note that if your server is blocking the edit of `.htaccess` file then it will not work. An error notification should appear. In that case you will need to ask your hosting provider to unblock the `.htaccess` file.

Your structure can be a custom one with `%author%/%post_id%` as a value.

Reference: https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-permalinks-screen/

Comment: Is it possible to use both types at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you can use `%author%/%post_id%` and not just `%author%`